# how to define getter so, that based on error code I can show error message instead of having multiple `if` statement

Tags: flutter, localization, getter-setter, getter, applocalizations

We are calling API and handling the exception.

```dart
class Failure with _$Failure  implements Exception  {
  
  factory Failure({
    required FetchError fetchError,
    required ServerError? errorCodeFromServer,
  }) = _Failure;
  

}
```

And, based on the exception type We are passing an error code when We are  throwing Failure based on catching an error. Now, that error code is passed on to the bloc. And, in then UI screen We are trying to show the error message in bloc listener like this

```dart
        if (state.loginStatus == LoginStatus.error) {
          simpleSnackbarMessage(
            context,
            l10n.[state.error],
            MessageType.failed,
          );
        }
```

now, We have `app_en.arb` file in that I have all the possible error messages. But, when We are trying to access like `l10n.[state.error],` it show an error.

```
The getter '[' isn't defined for the type 'AppLocalizations'.
```

So, my question

#### how to define getter so, that based on error code I can show error message instead of having multiple `if` statement.

[image]

Thanks :pray:

Comment: have you tried `l10n["${state.error}"]`??

Comment: nope I haven't tried. Let me try

Comment: getting the error `The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'AppLocalizations'.
Try defining the operator '[]'.` @suzan

Comment: @suzan currently this is how I can only access `  l10n.unknownError` but, We want that `unknowError` to be replaced with the `state.error` so, that it's dynamically show the message